# loopback notification with typescript

Tags: typescript, loopback

I have loopback api with typescript. 
 Api helps to purchase products. Lets say if someone is purchasing product x and makes changes in his order, we need to get notification on this activity on api side. 
What and how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Websocket with Loopback but it's not working natively, you need to work a bit around. There is a repo to show how to implement Websocket with Loopback4:
https://github.com/raymondfeng/loopback4-example-websocket/

Once you have these, you can then implement notifications easily.